# Why cant I send emails through Google Sheets using a Mobile device?

Tags: email, google-apps-script, mobile, google-sheets

I opened up a spreadsheet and inserted a Drawing to use it as an Action Button, then I assigned the following script to it:

```
function sendEmail() {
  var emailAddress = 'myemail@gmail.com';
  var message = 'test-message';
  var subject = 'test-subject';
   MailApp.sendEmail({
     to: emailAddress,
     subject: subject,
     htmlBody: message
   });
}
```

Everytime I click the button from a PC, it works fine, I receive the test email instantly. But when I try to test it using any sort of mobile device it won't let me click the button. 
Why hasn't google fixed this? 
How can I effectively make my script send an email from google sheets using a mobile device? I've already tried with onEdit() and data validation instead of buttons but this doesn't work with the *MailApp.sendEmail* function, so it doesn't resolve my problem.

Please help

Comment: Use installable edit trigger

Comment: Star this feature request: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/110165906

Answer (score 2):

This is a known [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/110165906)(Star it to show support). Apps Script works from official mobile apps, but buttons with scripts assigned to them do not.

`onEdit` simple trigger does not work because you need  email sending permissions. For  this case, an onEdit [Installable Trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) can be used.